# Javascript: how to modify my code to add back disappeared placeholder after topic post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, placeholder

I use a plug in to handmade a placeholder for conteditable div.

showed in demo below. If user puts in some text then click the post button, the placeholder disappeared.I wondered how to get the placeholder back after posting.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="topic_content_input" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" data-placeholder="placeholder text" ></div>
<button id="post">Post topic</button>

<style>
#topic_content_input[data-placeholder]:not([data-div-placeholder-content]):before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    float: left;
     cursor:text;
    margin-left: 2px;
    color: rgba(134,134,134,0.6);
}

#topic_content_input{
width:521px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

#topic_content_input:focus{
  outline-style:solid;
  outline-color:orange;
  outline-width:0px;
  line-height:normal;
}
</style>


 <script>
 (function ($) {
    $(document).on('change keydown keypress input', '#topic_content_input[data-placeholder]', function() {
        if (this.textContent) {
            this.dataset.divPlaceholderContent = 'true';
        }
        else {
            delete(this.dataset.divPlaceholderContent);
        }
    });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
<script>
$("#post").click(function(){
    $("#topic_content_input").text(""); 
    var obj=$("#topic_content_input");

    // $("#topic_content_input").add(obj.dataset.divPlaceholderContent);  //my attempt, not working
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CSS, rather than having `#topic_content_input[data-placeholder]:not([data-div-placeholder-content]):before`, you can instead put in `#topic_content_input:empty:before`, which will put in the placeholder whenever the div is empty, as seen in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9rgoL33/21/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#topic_content_input").add(obj.dataset.divPlaceholderContent);
```

why ".add" ?

you shoul use:

```
obj.val(obj.dataset.divPlaceholderContent)
```

or

```
obj.attr('placeholder', obj.dataset.divPlaceholderContent)
```